# Small caps given different letter sizes in acrobat pdf viewer

Tags: pdftex, small-caps

I am using \textsc{} in my latex document and in the pdf view for mac everything is fine, however when opening the document in Adobe Acrobat Reader on my windows machine the small cap letters are not all the same size.

In PDF viewer:

[image: PDF viewer on Mac]

In Adobe acrobat:

[image: Adobe Acrobat Reader]

(Sorry about different sizes in the images, but the problem is still visible)

Comment: Does the problem in Acrobat persist upon zoom?  Also, is hardcopy printout at the proper size?

Comment: Okay now I feel like a bit of an idiot, my acrobat document was zoomed out at 70%, at 100% looks fine. Thanks

Comment: It is disconcerting to see midword font changes like that.  Usually, however, it is purely a rendering issue, and not associated with the underlying TeX.  Zoom and printing are the diagnostic tools to determine if that is the case.  Happy LaTeXing, and welcome to the site.  Come back now, y'all.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comment.