# Capital letters not rendering well with low magnification

Tags: fonts

I am writing my PhD thesis and using small caps for subsection headings, however when I try viewing my thesis on Adobe Acrobat on Windows, the letters seem very wavy (see the "A" compared to the "W"):

[image]

Note that this question has also been asked in [Small caps given different letter sizes in acrobat pdf viewer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/302993/small-caps-given-different-letter-sizes-in-acrobat-pdf-viewer), but didn't get answered (except by saying that the author should zoom in more).

Is there a way around this issue (besides zooming)? I would like people to be able to read my thesis without getting a motion sick from reading these wavy headings.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{newpxtext}

\begin{document}

\section{THIS IS THE SECTION TITLE}
\lipsum[1]

\subsection{THIS IS THE SUBSECTION TITLE}

\lipsum[1]

\textsc{this is anoter test to check the waviness}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

Edit: compiled with `pdflatex` from TexLive 2017, and `newpxtext` from March 11, 2017. This issue does not show up on Linux with the Okular pdf reader or with the Preview app on Mac. Printing also looks good.

Comment: Tell us also how do you compile, the versions of the packages and of TeX system, etc.

Comment: I can confirm a similar effect with TeX Live 2016, pdflatex, `newpxtext` from March 11, 2017, and Adobe Acrobat 9 on Mac. Zooming helps. Mac-own Preview.app works fine. I'd expect no waviness in print.

Comment: The same issue occurs with Latin Modern. The only real solution is to choose a different font. Incidentally, I see the issue in Okular on Linux, too. Somebody said it is to do with them being badly hinted, but it may be more complicated than that. There really isn't anything you can do except use a different font.

Comment: Is that just a case of trial and error or are there examples of good fonts where this is not a problem? Since it also happens for Latin Modern, I assumed it happened for most fonts.

Comment: I see no problem with my PDF viewer: [see picture (click here)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vITJL.png)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the issue is a PDF viewer effect.

Comment: It happens to different extent for different pdf readers and operating systems. However, fonts are an important choice within latex, and one can pick fonts that do not have this issue. So I don't think it is off-topic at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be solved by switching to a different font. A font very similar to Palatino and that doesn't have this issue, is Minion Pro from Adobe. That font can be used with `pdflatex` through [FontPro](https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro), as long as you have the `.otf` files for Minion Pro.